# Custom Login Updating Details In Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to change or update user details while custom login. i have a table named student_table. there has some student details. With mail address and password i can login in dashboard. but in dashboard there is a page named setting page. with setting page i want to update phone, address and password number. but while trying or i click that page, the page is showing with blank page. the image is below, anything error or suggestion for updating controller code?

[image]

**My controller code**

```
public function student_settings()

    {
        $student_id = Session::get('student_id');
        $viewData = saveStudent::select('*') 
        -> where('student_id', $student_id)
        -> first();

       return view('student_settings', compact('viewData'));


    }
```

**View page Code**

```
@extends('student_layout')

@section('content')

   <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 grid-margin">
                  <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-body">
                          <h2 class="card-title">Update Your Details

 @if(count($errors) > 0)
@foreach($errors ->all() as $error)

              <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $error }} </div>

          @endforeach
          @endif


      @if(count($viewData)> 0)

  @foreach($viewData -> all() as $singleData)           

     <form class="forms-sample" method="post" action="">

        {{csrf_field()}}



                              <div class="form-group">

                                  <label for="exampleInputEmail6">Student Phone</label>

                                  <input type="text" id="exampleInputEmail6" class="form-control p-input" name="student_phone" placeholder="Enter PhoneNumber" value="{{$singleData->student_phone}}">

                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">

                                  <label for="exampleInputEmail7">Student Address</label>

                                  <input type="text" id="exampleInputEmail7" class="form-control p-input" name="student_address" placeholder="Enter Address" value="{{$singleData->student_address}}">
                              </div>

                               <div class="form-group">

                                  <label for="exampleInputEmail7">Student Password</label>

                                  <input type="password" id="exampleInputEmail7" class="form-control p-input" name="student_address" placeholder="Enter Address" value="{{$singleData->student_password}}">
                              </div>



                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                          </form>
                          @endforeach
                          @endif
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

        </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Please set writable permission to 'storage/logs' directory and see laravel.log file.

Comment: i can't understand that

Comment: Which operating system you are using?

Comment: Please set 777 folder permission to 'storage/logs' directory then repeat the above step and check if laravel.log file.

Comment: using windows 7

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you're checking if your **$viewData** has content in it before you render the form. Your **$viewData** variable is not returning any content.
Check the **select code** in your controller.

More about select query here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**I can see your `View page Code`**
In view page, You miss route action in `<form>`Tag so add following action.

```
action="{{ route('student_settings', $singleData->id) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It have to pass student_id from studentLogin Controller like this,
 `session(['student_id' => $take->student_id]);`